# Transaction causing stored procedure to hang

Tags: sql-server

We have a windows service that orchestrates imports to a database. The service itself isn’t the problem as this essentially just creates a scheduled job, waits until it completes and then fires a series of stored procs. The problem is that one of the procs appears to be getting stuck midway through. It’s not throwing an error and so I have nothing to that I can give as a definitive problem. I have narrowed it down to a single proc that gets called after the job has completed. I’ve even managed to narrow it down to a specific line of code, but that’s where I’m struggling.

The proc, will define a transaction name at the start, being the name of the proc and a datetime. It also gets a transaction count from `@@TranCount`. It then defines a cursor that loops the files associated with the event. Inside a `try` block it dynamically creates a view (which definitely happens as I write a log entry afterwards). Immediately after this, there is an `IF` condition that either creates or saves the transaction based on whether the variable holding `@@TranCount` is zero or not. Inside this condition I write a message to our log table BEFORE the transaction is created/saved.

Immediately after (regardless of whether it’s a create or a save) I write another log message. The log entry is there. The times we’ve seen this pausing, the proc always writes the create transaction log message. It doesn’t get as far as writing the message outside the condition. The only thing that happens between the first message (pre create/save trans) and the second message (post trans) is the create/save transaction. As the message being logged is the create message, there can’t be a transaction open (`@@TranCount` must have been zero). However, as no error is raised I can’t say with 100% certainty that this is the case. The line that seems to stop is the `CREATE TRANSACTION @TransactionName` line. This seems to imply that something is locking and preventing the statement from being executed. The problem is we can see no open transactions (`DBCC` reports nothing open), the proc just hangs there.

We’re fairly certain that it’s a lock of some description, but completely baffled as to what. To add a level of complexity, it doesn’t occur every time. Some times with the same file, we can run the process without any issue on this database. We’ve tried running the file against another database with no luck in replicating the problem, but we have seen it occur on other databases on this server (the server holds multiple client databases that do the same thing). This also only happens on this server.  We have other servers in the environment, with seemingly identical configs, where we haven't seen this issue surface.

Unfortunately we can’t post any of the code due to internal rules, but any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: So you need help debugging some pretty complex code that has a lot of conditions and transaction but you can't share any of the code. How exactly do you expect anybody to actually be able to help you here?

Comment: I'm not really after debugging per say. Given this is only happening on this server I thought there may be some configuration setting that we've potentially overlooked.  I was really after any input that could help, but I fully appreciate not being able to share the code isn't help.  I'll see if I can obfuscate the code somehow.

Comment: Well from your comments there are a few red flags to me. Things like dynamically creating views, cursors etc all with transactions. The problem is almost certainly blocking but this kind of thing can be incredibly difficult to isolate when you are sitting at the machine with full access. Across the internet with nothing more than a partial explanation of the process it is next to impossible. It could be any of a zillion things. I wish it were something simpler we could help with.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com) and enable the lock flag. I also recommend finding the query plan with the code below and analyzing the stats there.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT DB_NAME(p.dbid) AS DBName ,
OBJECT_NAME(p.objectid, p.dbid) AS OBJECT_NAME ,
cp.usecounts ,
p.query_plan ,
q.text ,
p.dbid ,
p.objectid ,
p.number ,
p.encrypted ,
cp.plan_handle
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) p
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) AS q
WHERE cp.cacheobjtype = 'Compiled Plan'
)a WHERE text LIKE '%SNIPPET OF SQL GOES HERE THAT IS PART OF THE QUERY YOU WANT TO FIND%'
ORDER BY dbid, objectID
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about checking the connection properties for the service? If this is set too low and the proc takes longer to run this will cause it to drop the connection and kill of the process.

This is much more likely than it being anything to do with the name of the transaction.